# Installing windows 10 on blank thinkpad

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

i am helping a freind install windows on their thinkpad using a usb stick i went into the bios and put usb on the top of the boot oreder turned it on and lo and behold ubuntu booted so i went back to the bios looked ubuntu was at the top of the boot order so i removed it from the boot order and turned it on and ubuntu booted i looked in the bios there it was at the top of the boot order finaly i tried one more thing i used rm -rf / it worked i rebooted and got a screen saying to pick a bootable device i picked the usb drive (it was the only option ) it rebooted back to that screen so im wondering what i should do
i am mostly sure that i saved the bios right
Update i forgot about secure boot it might have that enabeld

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry to clarify i am looking for an way to install windows

Comment: Some grammar and formatting and punctuation would go s long way towards making this question more helpful for others, which is one of the goals of this site.

Comment: Even if there was proper grammar and punctuation, it's still very unclear what the question is in the 1st place. Proper question should be **as specific as possible** and also end with a `?` character.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://superuser.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: ok sorry should i delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot to BIOS, make sure nothing more unneeded is in the Boot order.

Now reset BIOS to default, save and exit.

Now start with a Lenovo or  a Microsoft Windows 10 USB and install Windows.

That should work and it does on my Lenovo computers.

Comment: thank you ill try that